# Decrease an image quality before rendering it on a vue app

Tags: image, vue.js, image-processing, vuetify.js

I am trying to reduce the load time of my web pages, however I have a lot of images on my front page and those images are high resolution. The main page shows a gallery of those photos in a small scale 256x256, which doesn't need to keep its high resolution. Is there a way to decrease the size and the resolution of those images in my vue app directly ? I am also using Vuetify with my app.

Answer (score 0):

While it certainly **is** possible to reduce the resolution of your images, directly in your Vue app, it wouldn't solve your problem - it might even make your Vue app less performant. The Vue app runs entirely in the browser (unless you're using server-side rendering). Therefore the high resolution images would still have to be downloaded, before any image processing library can reduce them in the Vue app. Having to download the files means that the load time wouldn't change. In fact, letting the browser do the processing would cause it to use the users computer resources, instead of your servers.

You're better off reducing the image resolution server side (or at "compile" time, if the images are static):

- You can reduce the resolution each time an image is downloaded, and then use caching to avoid processing the same image over and over.
- You can do it when the image is uploaded, and store the low resolution image in your file storage.
- A combination of the above, where you lazily reduce the resolution when an image is downloaded, and then store the low resolution version for use with any subsequent request.

If the images are merely static images for your Vue application, there exists build tools which hook into the Vue-cli build pipeline, that can optimize images for production when the application is being built. Then you simply upload the optimized images when the application is deployed.